# Is it safe to remote true from boolean props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a huge codebase and there is a linter that I need to apply on it and make sure it follows the guidelines.

One philosophy of this linter is to remove redundant boilerplate code.

And one item that it complains about is boolean props. For example `<Employee isActive={true} />` should become `<Employee isActive />`

Now I'm thinking about finding all `={true}` instances and delete them all.

Is it safe to do that for all components?

Because as much as I know, if you don't pass a value for a prop, it becomes a boolean prop and its presence means its value is true. Is there any other situation that I'm not aware of regarding passing props without values?

Comment: That should be fine. ESLint has a `--fix` flag that will automatically fix issues that it can, if that's the linter you're using.

Comment: @Nick, it's a commercial linter that our company has bought. It's not ESLint. Thank you for the assurance.

Comment: Toy should use a `codemod` for that